# как с помощью Javascript или jquery заменить тег?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Есть код:

```
<div class="class-1"> бла бла бла </div>
```

Нужно чтобы при загрузке страницы тег `div` заменялся на `span`. Не нужно заменять целый блок див, а нужно чтобы содержимое оставалось таким же, только вместо `div` чтобы был `span`.

Спасибо

Comment: блин. код не вставился

Comment: <div class="class-1"> Бла бла бла </div>

Comment: Нельзя переименовать тег. Можно создать новый тег и положить в него содержимое старого.

Comment: @AlexeyTen забудьте слово "нельзя". в программировании можно все.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын и что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться [replaceWith](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), с помощью которого можно заменять элементы страницы новыми элементами или уже существующими.

```js
$('div.inner').replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<span />", {html: $(this).html()});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner second">And</div>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

или

```js
$('div.inner').replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<span />").append($(this).contents());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner second">And</div>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

[документация на английском](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Answer (score 3):

еще вариант без jQuery, с использованием [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild)

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.inner'), function(divInner) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = divInner.innerHTML;
  divInner.parentNode.replaceChild(span, divInner);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner second">And</div>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение на "чистом" *JavaScript* без использования дополнительных библиотек:

```
/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} element Элемент, имя тэга которого будет заменено.
 * @param {String} newTagName Новое имя тэга.
 */
function replaceTag(element, newTagName) {
    // Создаём новый тэг.
    var newTag = document.createElement(newTagName);

    // Вставляем новый тэг перед старым.
    element.parentElement.insertBefore(newTag, element);

    // Переносим в новый тэг атрибуты старого с их значениями.
    for (var i = 0, attrs = element.attributes, count = attrs.length; i < count; ++i)
        newTag.setAttribute(attrs[i].name, attrs[i].value);

    // Переносим в новый тэг все дочерние элементы старого.
    var childNodes = element.childNodes;
    while (childNodes.length > 0)
        newTag.appendChild(childNodes[0]);

    // Удаляем старый тэг.
    element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
}
```